# how can I get the actual exception from remote webservice in silverlight client?

Tags: silverlight, web-services, exception

```
[WebMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
```

I want get the actual Exception (eg:ArgumentNullException) in silverlight client webservice call completed method. how can i implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The Completed event should have two parameters it is expecting back: object sender, and the event's CompletedEventArgs collection, named e.

The completed event args contains an Exception, e.Error, which should be the exception that was returned.

Comment: yes. It has e.error and  can get some message from e.error.Message.But  this is not the actual Exception from remote webservice.

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    } this cause a exception,but I dont know its a ArgumentNullException ,the CompletedEventArgs e.error.message just return NOT FOUND

Comment: You could always opt to return a result string to indicate success or failure of the call, with a user-friendly error message if that's the end goal (simply to notify the user more accurately what has happened).